# How to read the file line by line and to print the previous line where the file contains a single token

Tags: text-processing

For example my file is like:

```
59 6 18 2014 169 7 14 2 7671912 7849744 201 4
60 6 19 2014 170 5 49 2 7671912 7849744 201 5
61 6 20 2014 171 6 8 2 7671912 7849744 201 6
62 6 23 2014 174 5 3 2 7671912 7849744 201 7
63 6 23 2014 174 7 17 2 7671912 7849744 201 8
64 6 24 2014 175 16 13 2 7671912 7849744 201 9
65 6 25 2014 176 8 20 2 7671912 7849744 201 10
10
1 1 49 6 16 2014 7 39 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
1 2 49 6 17 2014 13 15 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
1 3 49 6 18 2014 1 38 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
1 4 49 6 18 2014 7 14 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
1 5 49 6 19 2014 5 49 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
```

I need to print the previous line of single token entry "10" which should be

```
65 6 25 2014 176 8 20 2 7671912 7849744 201 10
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```
awk 'NF == 1 { print LAST } { LAST=$0 }' < datafile
```

This saves every line of the file (`LAST=$0`) as it goes, and when a line has only one record (`NF == 1` - `NF` is the number of tokens on the line, roughly speaking) it prints the saved previous line out.

Comment: +1 but it might be better to use `$0 == "10"` instead. I think the OP meant a specific "token".

Comment: now i need to traverse through the result and need to check  9th position,11th position,13th,15th etc till the end of the line with the consecutive odd positions and if those are not matching with any of the mentioned numerics 201 230 197 193 229 200 215 226 001 198 it should throw an print the error as  CORRUPTED, if not AVAILABLE should be printed. (if we cosider this as example 9th position is 7671912) NOTE : The code should be feasible at any other file as well.

Comment: now i need to traverse through the result and need to check  9th position,11th,13th etc till the end of the line with the consecutive odd positions and if those positions are not matching with any of the mentioned numerics 201 230 197 193 229 200 215 226 001 198 it should print the error as  CORRUPTED,if not AVAILABLE should be printed. (if we cosider this as example 9th position is 7671912) NOTE : The code should be feasible at any other file as well. The code which i wrote for the result is #! /bin/ksh

file=input.txt
while read line
do
awk 'NF == 1 { print LAST } { LAST=$0 }'
done < "$file"

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one occurrence of the token, you could do this with GNU `grep` and `head`:

```
grep -x -B 1 10 file | head -n 1
```

The `-B 1` tells `grep` to print the matching line and the one before it. With the `-x` option, `grep 10` matches on lines that are e`x`actly `10` (as opposed to *containing* `10`). Finally, the `head -n 1` prints only the first of the resulting lines.

Answer (score 1):

### sed

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^10$/{x;p;}' -e 'x;d' < datafile
```

Explanation:

The address `/^10$/` matches the line containing 10. When it matches, the following series of commands is run, `{x;p;}`, which exchanges (`x`) the hold space with the pattern space and then prints (`p`) the pattern space.

The hold space contains the previous line because of the rest of the script. For each line of the file, exchange (`x`) the hold space with the pattern space, and then delete (`d`) whatever is in the pattern space.

Unlike the first command, which has an address prefix that causes it to only match when the 10 line is seen, these commands have no prefix, and thus match on every line of the file. The net result is that we keep putting the last line seen into the hold space, and the fact that we delete the pattern space means that there is no output other than our explicit output when we see 10.

Comment: As Michael homer suggested, the command is working, now I need to check the 9th position,11th,13th etc till the end of the line with the consecutive odd positions and if those positions are not matching with any of the mentioned numerics 
201 
230 
197 
193 
229 
200 
215 
226 
001 
198 
it should print the error as CORRUPTED,if not AVAILABLE should be printed.
Note : The code should be feasible for any kind of the data

Comment: You can use `cut` or `awk` to break up the line and extract the items you wish to test (or `perl`, or other things), and you can use `grep -F -f <file>` to test them against a fixed list of strings, but you should really ask another question about this.